# How to clip drawables with xml files?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm trying to create an overlay for the corners in my app.
I want them to be rounded and black all the time like this:

[image: Attached Image]

I created it with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
        <corners android:radius="24dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Then I added it to my theme as an android:windowFrame:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@drawable/corner_overlay</item>
</style>
```

But obviosly everything was white then. Now I'm trying to clip the second shape instead of coloring it white and if that doesnt work I'm looking for another way to get my corner overlay working!

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Tested your drawable and it worked on my device. Do you wrapped your items in layer-list?

Comment: Yes I did (don't know why this is not visible here), but the second "rectangle" is white so it completely covers and hides my app. I want just the corners to be seen, so I'm looking for a way to clip the second item instead of coloring it white. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Another way is using custom layouts. I'll publish quick code in answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom Frame Layout and wrap all your content with it.

```
class RoundedCornerLayout : FrameLayout {

private var paint: Paint? = null
private var paint2: Paint? = null
private var cornerRadius: Float = 10f

private var mWidth: Int = 0
private var mHeight: Int = 0

constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    init(context, null, 0)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    init(context, attrs, 0)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    init(context, attrs, defStyle)
}

private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
    val metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
    cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics)

    paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    paint?.color = Color.BLACK

    paint2 = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    paint2?.color = Color.TRANSPARENT
    paint2?.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)

    setWillNotDraw(false)
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
}

override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    mWidth = w
    mHeight = h
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    canvas?.drawRect(0f, 0f, mWidth.toFloat(), mHeight.toFloat(), paint)
    canvas?.drawRoundRect(RectF(0f, 0f, mWidth.toFloat(), mHeight.toFloat()), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint2)
}

companion object {
    private val CORNER_RADIUS = 40.0f
}
}
```

And use it in your xml:

```
<com.dantes.backstack.RoundedCornerLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <!-- Your content here-->

</com.dantes.backstack.RoundedCornerLayout>
```

Of course this is draft and you need to optimize it and make more clear to your purposes. But principal part is PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR). This mode make magic and cuts the tarnsparent rectangle from the dark.

Maybe it will help or at least push your minds in right direction.

Comment: Hey buddy, the Kotlin code (I belive it's Kotlin, I translated it to Java) works but I have problems adding it to my theme, because it is a layout and not a drawable. Is there a way to cast it to a drawable or do you know how to make it a custom drawable instead of a custom layout?

Comment: Because the main feature is the drawing, you may draw this two rectangles to the bitmap using canvas (without using layout, you can draw it even in some activity). This way gives you a single bitmap and you can use it like a simple image. But it also not the drawable. And I don't know how it will affect the performance of your application

Comment: You can also read some info about 9-patch images and experiment with that format. It might be helpful